# move PointClouds / sprites along a geometry. THREE.JS

Tags: animation, three.js, particles, tween.js

I have a curved line, I would like to know how do PointClouds or sprites to move along this line. I want to do something like this: http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/ how can I do it?. You can make it easier using tween.js?

[image]

I have this is a mesh tube that also I have a line, how I can do to make a sprite / PointCloud move along its structure?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mflux.tumblr.com/post/28367579774/armstradeviz)? I do remember reading a more in depth article on how the global arms experiment was made which went into detail about how the lines and particle were done, but I cant seem to find it.

Comment: The source code for the chrome experiment can be inspected via the developer tools and you can see how it is done.

Comment: @WestLangley if you need to use the code is somehow easier or tween.js example code seems complicated.